# Работа с большим тхт C# Применение многопоточности

Tags: c#

Добрый день, есть файл тхт (может достигать пару ГБ), текст в тхт примерно такой :

```
ABCD--
sdfdsf
sdfsdf
sdfsd
ABCD--
sdfdsf2
sdfsdf2
sdfsd2
ABCD--
sdfdsf3
sdfsdf3
sdfsd3
и тд
```

нужно скопировать от ABCD-- до ABCD-- и вставить в новый файл. В принципе, такое решается с помощью регулярки, пугает лишь то, что вес тхт файла слишком большой, и хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение, как лучше реализовать, чтоб потратить меньше всего времени (возможно применить сюда многопоточность).

Пока реализовал так :

```
string txt = File.ReadAllText("1.txt");
var RegexPattern = @"ABCD--([\s\S]*?)ABCD--";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(txt, RegexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

int c = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    File.WriteAllText("text-"+rnd.Next(1,10000).ToString(),match.Value);
}
```

Жду ваших комментариев и советов, спасибо

Comment: Читать обычным циклом с отсечением по ABCD--. Хватит и одного потока - все упрется в I/O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете ускорить процесс, если не будете читать весь файл в память. Обрабатывайте файл построчно.

Это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
var pattern = "ABCD--";
StreamWriter outf = null;
try
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("1.txt"))
    {
        if (line == pattern)
        {
            if (outf != null)
            {
                outf.Dispose();
                outf = null;
                continue;
            }

            outf = File.CreateText(...);
        }

        if (outf != null)
            outf.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (outf != null)
        outf.Dispose();
}
```

---

Обновлённый вариант по уточнённому условию:

```
var pattern = "ABCD--";
StreamWriter outf = File.CreateText(...);
try
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("1.txt"))
    {
        if (line == pattern)
        {
            outf.Dispose();
            outf = File.CreateText(...);
        }
        else
        {
            outf.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    outf.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: да, спасибо, действительно быстрее работает. Только я не учел одну вещь, последняя запись в тхт выглядит так :
`ABCD--
sdfdsf3
sdfsdf3
sdfsd3`
 тобишь, без `ABCD--` и получается, что `sdfdsf3...` не идет в отдельный файл

Comment: Хотя нет, не совсем корректно работает, если в `1.txt` будет текст, что я привел в топике, то в результате появятся 2 файла, в одном будет `sdfdsf ... `, в другом `sdfsdf3..`. при этом `sdfsdf2 ..`- пропускается

Comment: @Lolidze: А, вам нужно, чтобы с `ABCD--` начинался новый файл каждый раз? А начало файла, что с ним?

Comment: Да, начинался новый файл. Перед началом `ABCD`-- может быть что угодно, потом уже начинается блок `ABCD`-- , а за ним еще один блок `ABCD`-- и тп. Простите, что сразу это не уточнил, я какт не подумал об этом

Comment: Проблема решилась добавлением проверки на null (изначально outf= null, как и в 1 примере), спасибо @FoggyFinder и вам огромное спасибо за помощь !!!

Comment: @Lolidze: А что насчёт кода в обновлённом варианте?

Comment: Если начальный кусок надо пропускать, то тогда да, проверка на `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте считывать так:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (!line.Equals("ABCD--"))
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("text-" + new Random().Next(1, 10000).ToString() + ".txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь